# Kendo UI chart data value is not shown correctly

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am having a trouble to customize the kendo chart in order that all of my data in the chart is shown correctly. As you can see on the picture bellow, the value of my data is cutted on half.
As the data is assigned dinamicaly, it's not possible to set the constant size of a chart in order to fix the problem.

Is there any option to set (f.e. css property) to fix this issue?

Or is there any way to manipulate the "max" property of a valueAxis to be always 10% bigger than the maximum loaded value.

I've already tried playing with margins and padding, or changing the width of a chart, but problem is still there.

Here is the photo:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? can you show you chart configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to increase the right margin of the plotArea:

```
plotArea: {
  margin: {
    right: 30
  }
},
```

Another option is to change the **[label position](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.position)**

```
seriesDefaults: {
    type: "bar",
    labels: {
       visible: true,
       background: "transparent",
       position: "insideEnd"
    }
},
```

Comment: The first option works fine, thanks! I was familiar with second option, but it was not the solution I needed. Thanks again @ezanker